# Transfering Data From BigQuery Datasets to my Own Created BigQuery Table

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a project in big query with its all datasets now I want to know how data is coming from firebase to those datasets, And I have created one new own table in bigquery. How can I push the data from any tables of dataset to my own created table?
This query contains all the fields of the dataset table which I want to in my own table.

```
SELECT
user_dim.device_info.device_category
user_dim.device_info.mobile_brand_name  

user_dim.device_info.mobile_model_name  
user_dim.device_info.mobile_marketing_nam
FROM [in_mylo_pregnancy_baby_app_ANDROID.app_events]
```

Comment: Do you want `user_dim.device_info.device_category` to have that name in the new table? Or will it be called simply `deviceCategory`? What is wrong with the query that you provided in your question?

Comment: "user_dim.device_info.device_category" This is a column in the table which is  (Automatically) provided by firebase in the big query. I want to take data from this table to my own created table in the big query. How i will do

Comment: And one more help i want to know or understand  the structure of the table provided by firebase into the bigQuery.. Can u help me with that also??

Comment: Yes its a simple device category i just want to take data from this table under this column( "User_dim.device_info.device_category") to my new table created manually in the bigQuery..

Comment: You didn't answer my question. In the new table, is the column called `user_dim.device_info.device_category`, or is it called `device_category`?

Comment: Its a device category only..

Comment: one more question is I have a dataset under my project in BigQuery and under that dataset i have some tables . i m trying to see the data from one table by putting below query but it is not working. How this will work..

Comment: Select * from DatasetName.TableName;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `user_dim` is an array, you can use a query such as this one. Make sure to include the `#standardSQL`.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_dim.device_info.device_category
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_brand_name  
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_model_name  
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_marketing_nam
FROM `in_mylo_pregnancy_baby_app_ANDROID.app_events`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(user_dim) AS user_dim;
```

Now all of the fields will be top level columns in the resulting table. If it is not an array, then just select those fields directly:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_dim.device_info.device_category
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_brand_name  
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_model_name  
  user_dim.device_info.mobile_marketing_nam
FROM `in_mylo_pregnancy_baby_app_ANDROID.app_events;
```

Please stop trying to ask multiple questions, since that is not how StackOverflow works. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).